# How can two developers publish one android app?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Me and my friend are working on an Android app.
Is it possible to have two developers for one app on the Play store?
If yes, how?
If not, what do we do?
Both of us will be contributing equally and it will be unfair to publish the app on only one's account.

Note: We don't want to create a company or get into a legal binding.

Comment: you want to make a copy of your own app in market?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publishing policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of you can the owner of your Developer Console, and invite the other as a user.

- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

Comment: if an account has one owner and one user, What name will be displayed as the Developer of the app on play store ?

Comment: The name of the owner will be displayed. The other one has to be generous, I guess.